# How to fix "ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List" for TokenCredential in Azure

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-storage, access-token, azure-resource-manager

I am using following dependencies along with other required with their corresponding versions as shown below:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure', version:'2.1.13.RELEASE'
compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-core-management', version: '1.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.2.2'
    compile group: 'com.azure.resourcemanager', name: 'azure-resourcemanager-storage', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '1.3.1'
    compile group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-core', version: '3.4.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-client-authentication', version: '1.4.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter:2.3.5'
```

code snippet is as follows:

```
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.core.http.rest.Response;
import com.azure.core.management.exception.ManagementException;
import com.azure.core.management.profile.AzureProfile;
import com.azure.core.util.Context;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.resources.fluentcore.utils.HttpPipelineProvider;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.StorageManager;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.fluent.models.ManagementPolicyInner;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.implementation.StorageManagementClientBuilder;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.implementation.StorageManagementClientImpl;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.models.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class BLMRule{

  @Value("${azure.resourcegroup:}")
  private static String resourceGroup;

  @Value("${azure.storageaccount:}")
  private static String storageAcc;

  @Value("${azure.container:}")
  private static String prefixForRule;

  @Autowired private TokenCredential credential;
  @Autowired private AzureProfile profile;

  private static String BLOCK_BLOB = "blockBlob";
  private static String LIFECYCLE_NAME_PREFIX = "policy";
  private static String SLASH = "/";
  private StorageManager manager;


  @Override
  public boolean createLifeCyclePolicy(int days, String azureRuleName) throws JsonProcessingException {
   
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ManagementPolicy managementPolicy = null;
    boolean createFirstEverPolicy = false;
    String azureRuleNamePrefix = prefixForRule + SLASH + azureRuleName + SLASH;

    manager = StorageManager.authenticate(credential, profile);

    
      managementPolicy = manager.managementPolicies().getAsync(resourceGroup, storageAcc).block();

          // create new rule
          createNewPolicy(profile, credential, azureRuleNamePrefix, days, createFirstEverPolicy);
        
    }

    return true;
  }

  public static void createNewPolicy(
      AzureProfile profile,
      TokenCredential credential,
      String inputRulename,
      int days,
      boolean createFirstEverPolicy) {
    String newLifeCyclePolicyName = LIFECYCLE_NAME_PREFIX + inputRulename;
    String prefixForinputRulename = prefixForRule + "/" + inputRulename + "/";
    StorageManagementClientImpl storageManagementClient =
        new StorageManagementClientBuilder()
            .pipeline(HttpPipelineProvider.buildHttpPipeline(credential, profile))
            .endpoint(profile.getEnvironment().getResourceManagerEndpoint())
            .subscriptionId(profile.getSubscriptionId())
            .buildClient();

    ManagementPolicyDefinition definition =
        new ManagementPolicyDefinition()
            .withActions(
                new ManagementPolicyAction()
                    .withBaseBlob(
                        new ManagementPolicyBaseBlob()
                            .withDelete(
                                new DateAfterModification()
                                    .withDaysAfterModificationGreaterThan(days))))
            .withFilters(
                new ManagementPolicyFilter()
                    .withBlobTypes(Arrays.asList(BLOCK_BLOB))
                    .withPrefixMatch(Arrays.asList(prefixForinputRulename)));

    ManagementPolicyRule newRule =
        new ManagementPolicyRule()
            .withName(newLifeCyclePolicyName)
            .withEnabled(true)
            .withType(RuleType.LIFECYCLE)
            .withDefinition(definition);

    ManagementPolicySchema managementPolicySchema = new ManagementPolicySchema();
    List<ManagementPolicyRule> listOfRules = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfRules.add(newRule);
    managementPolicySchema.withRules(listOfRules);

    ManagementPolicyInner policyInner = null;
    if (createFirstEverPolicy) {
      policyInner = new ManagementPolicyInner();
      policyInner.withPolicy(managementPolicySchema);

    } else {
      policyInner =
          storageManagementClient
              .getManagementPolicies()
              .get(resourceGroup, storageAcc, ManagementPolicyName.DEFAULT);
      policyInner.policy().rules().add(newRule);
    }

    Response<ManagementPolicyInner> res =
        storageManagementClient
            .getManagementPolicies()
            .createOrUpdateWithResponse(
                resourceGroup,
                storageAcc,
                ManagementPolicyName.DEFAULT,
                policyInner.policy(),
                Context.NONE);
  }


}
```

**createLifeCyclePolicy** this method is getting called.
and beans- credential, profile are created as follows :

```
@Bean
  public AzureProfile profile() {
    return new AzureProfile(tenantId, subId, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenCredential credential() {
    AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(tenantId, subId, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
    return new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
        .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
        .tenantId(tenantId)
        .build();
  }
```

when I deploy my application, its giving following error :

```
2021-03-17 08:34:42:972 [,,,] [ERROR] - com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:184) - [Correlation ID: 88a40a02-b088-4674-95a9-92bd3d4350a0] Request to acquire token failed.
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.util.URLUtils.serializeParameters(URLUtils.java:101) ~[oauth2-oidc-sdk-7.4.jar!/:7.4]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.toOAuthRequest(AdalTokenRequest.java:151) ~[adal4j-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:84) ~[adal4j-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:880) ~[adal4j-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:68) ~[adal4j-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:176) [adal4j-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:165) [adal4j-1.3.0.jar!/:1.3.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

**How to fix this exception??**

Comment: Could you share the code that you faced this error?

Comment: Hi @Pamela Peng, I have edited and added code snippet, please check .

Answer (score 1):

This error is considered here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/650

You have to exclude com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk dependency and add the separate one to dependencies with a lower version (try 5.64.4)